# How to override matTreeNodePadding style in Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

There is Material Attribute `matTreeNodePadding` that sets padding-left for DOM element:

```
<div matTreeNodePadding></div>
```

After rendering this block comes to:

```
   <div style="padding-left: 40px;"></div>
```

How to reduce this padding to 20px?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of angular material? matTreeNodePadding should be used with a matree and mattree node component from the library and matTreeNodePadding is only an input of this component. https://material.angular.io/components/tree/api

Comment: Yes, I have read, but there is no solutions in docs

Comment: So if you have read the doc, you will don't use matTreeNodePadding like that. `<div matTreeNodePadding></div>` Is not an attribute of a div. Should be used with a tree node.

Comment: I got you, but anyway if you matTreeNodePadding with tree material it sets padding left. I need change it

Comment: `  <mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding>`

Comment: `@Input('matTreeNodePadding')
level: number

The level of depth of the tree node. The padding will be level * indent pixels.` Just read the doc before posting on stackoverflow.  matTreeNodePadding is an input so you should do something like that `[matTreeNodePadding]="20"`

Comment: Do you mean this? ` <mat-tree-node [matTreeNodePadding]="10" [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': level * 10}">` ?

Comment: No sorry, try something like that : `<mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding matTreeNodePaddingIndent="20">` or `<mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding [matTreeNodePaddingIndent]="20">` let me know if it's work

Comment: Yes, it works, could you post this as answers, I will accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `matTreeNodePadding` is a directive build for `mat-tree` and `mat-tree-node` component, should be used like that :

`<mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding matTreeNodePaddingIndent="20">`
or
`<mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding [matTreeNodePaddingIndent]="20">`